# Splitting and parsing a String value in a pre-defined pattern in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Can someone please help me with how can a string value be converted into a predefined format by splitting the string?

For example:
If the

```
Stringvalue = "20210819"
    
    needs to be converted as "08/19/2021"
    
    (Splitting first four and then next two and again next two)
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can either use "plain" string manipulation (like `val[0..3]` etc) or parse it as a date and format the result. The latter has the [dis]advantage of doing date-y things, the former is simple and clear. Is there a reason neither of those meets your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @DaveNewton, I was able to do that as you suggested.

```
Stringvalue = "20210819"
valuedate=Stringvalue
valueyear=(valuedate[0..3]);
valuemonth=(valuedate[4..5]);
valueday=(valuedate[6..7]);
println (valuemonth+"/"+valueday+"/"+valueyear);
```